# Website asking for verification code when logged in using casperjs or a new browser

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs, headless-browser

Trying to login into `admin.booking.com` and scrap out all the bookings of my hotel from the reservation page. But the thing is whenever I login using CasperJS or from a new location (new browser) it's asking for phone verification. Its redirecting the reservation page to phone verification page. Here is my code

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true, 
    logLevel: 'debug',
    viewportSize: {width: 950, height: 950}
});

casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36');

casper.start('https://admin.booking.com/', function() {
    //this.captureSelector('bhuwan1.png', 'body');
});

casper.then(function(){

    this.evaluate(function(){

       document.getElementById("loginname").value="1123123";
       document.getElementById("password").value="*******";
    });
});



casper.then(function(){

//$("button").eq(1).click();
this.click('button.btn-primary');
//this.wait(10000);
    console.log("first wait for 10sec");
});

casper.then(function(){
    this.wait(10000);
});


casper.then(function(){

var ses = this.getCurrentUrl().split("ses=")[1].split("&")[0];
console.log(ses);
//this.wait(10000);
console.log("first wait for 10sec");
var url = "https://admin.booking.com/hotel/hoteladmin/extranet_ng/manage/search_reservations.html?stay_to=2017-01-08&stay_from=2017-01-07&type=arrival&hotel_id=xxxxx&ses="+ses;

console.log(url);

this.evaluate(function(url){
var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
  var newContent = document.createElement("a");

 newContent.setAttribute("href",url);
   newContent.innerText="button";
   newDiv.appendChild(newContent);

  document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
  this.wait(10000);


},url);

});

casper.then(function(){

this.clickLabel("button",'a');
});


casper.then(function(){
    this.wait(10000);
    console.log("first wait for 10sec");

   this.capture('stack15.png', {
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width:1000,
        height: 2000
    });

   this.captureSelector('bhuwan15.png', 'body');

});



casper.run();
```

How to avoid the phone verification page and login as if its getting logged in from the familiar or old browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use authentication which is based on a cookie.
You need to find minimal amount of cookie that is needed to keeping your session. After that, you need to add into your script something like:

```
phantom.cookies = [{// an array of objects
  'name'     : 'theAuthCookie',
  'value'    : '<very long string>',
  'domain'   : 'www.wikifolio.com',
  'path'     : '/',
  'httponly' : false,
  'secure'   : true,
  'expires'  : (new Date()).getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 43800) //5 years
},{ 'name'     : 'DisclaimerCountryPopupV2',
  'value'    : 'de',
  'domain'   : 'www.wikifolio.com',
  'path'     : '/',
  'httponly' : false,
  'secure'   : true,
  'expires'  : (new Date()).getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 43800) }]
```

See also: [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40913039/cant-get-login-with-casperjs-to-work/40923768#40923768)

> You also need to use the `--cookies-file` option:

```
./casperjs --cookies-file=./my_file test.js >/dev/stdout
```

---

You need to use `--debug=true` command-line option if there is any problem.

These callbacks may also be useful:

```
casper
.on("error", function(msg){ this.echo("error: " + msg, "ERROR") })
.on("page.error", function(msg, trace){ this.echo("Page Error: " + msg, "ERROR") })
.on("remote.message", function(msg){ this.echo("Info: " + msg, "INFO") })
.on("resource.error", function(resourceError){
    console.log('Unable to load resource (#' + resourceError.id + 'URL:' + resourceError.url + ')');
    console.log('Error code: ' + resourceError.errorCode + '. Description: ' + resourceError.errorString);
});
```

Comment: how to use the cookies file option what is my_file

Comment: `--cookies-file=/path/to/cookies.txt` specifies the file name to store the persistent Cookies. PhantomJS -- [Command-line Options](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html).

I also think, it may not be needed, or you can try it without setting up the `phantom.cookies`.

Comment: without setting phatom.cookies it worked just transferred all the cookies to cookies.txt .Thanks

Comment: running the code in nodejs command prompt in my system its working but not working in aws ubuntu .help